# Error recuperando datos desde una consulta directa con FromSQLRaw de EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo este contexto

```
public class SAPBoletusContext : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<LicitacionesEnSolitarioSAP> LicitacionesEnSolitario { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

        modelBuilder.Entity<LicitacionesEnSolitarioSAP>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.OfertaId, c.CodigoSAP });

        modelBuilder.Entity<LicitacionesEnSolitarioSAP>()
            .Property(b => b.Plazo)
            .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LicitacionesEnSolitarioSAP>()
            .Property(b => b.FechaAdjudicacion)
            .IsRequired(false);
}
```

y esta entidad

```
public class LicitacionesEnSolitarioSAP
{

    public string CodigoSAP { get; set; }

    public string OfertaId { get; set; }

    public bool Adjudicado { get; set; }

    public string Plazo { get; set; }

    public decimal PresupuestoOfertado { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaAdjudicacion { get; set; }

}
```

Quiero ejecutar esta query que me duevelve 1500 registos

[image: query]

```
public int ImportarLicitacionesEnSolitario()
{
 try
 {
  int registrosAñadidos = 0;

  var registrosSAP = _contextSAP.LicitacionesEnSolitario
                .FromSqlRaw(@"select ot.CODIGOANALIZADA as OfertaId, 
                                     l.CardCode as CodigoSAP, 
                                     ot.ADJUDICADA as Adjudicado,
                                     ot.PLAZO as Plazo,
                                     ot.PRESUPUESTO as PresupuestoOfertado,
                                     o.FECHAADJUDICACION as FechaAdjudicacion
                            from ofertantes ot INNER JOIN licitadores l on           ot.idlicitador=l.idlicitador
                            inner join ofertas o on o.codigoanalizada=ot.codigoanalizada
                            inner join Fulcrum.dbo.OCRD ic on l.cardcode=ic.cardcode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            where year(o.fechapres)>=2015 AND   
                            ot.idlicitador in(
                            select IDLICITADOR  from LICITADORES
                            GROUP by IDLICITADOR
                            HAVING  COUNT(*)=1 
                            )
                            order by OfertaId, CodigoSAP")
                .ToList();

            foreach (var registroSAP in registrosSAP)
            {
             ...
```

Pero antes de llegar al foreach ya recibo ests excepcion System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueExcpetion

Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Cuado la query devuelve los registros que he mostrado

Alguna idea, por favor?

Un saludo